# How to use worker-loader in electron main process

Tags: javascript, electron, worker-loader

I configured the [worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader) in the renderer process and it worked fine. However, the same configuration doesn't work in the main process, it will throw an error "Worker is not defined".

I know that the Worker is different in the Node.js environment. How can I set it 
up properly?

Comment: you cannot. worker-loader currently doesn't implement node.js side worker setup.

Comment: Alright. I guess I have to implement those logics in the renderer and `remote.require` all the node.js module.